# Assign even odd page numbers in word

Tags: vba, ms-word, page-numbering

I am trying to write a vba macro for word, where the document will have page numbers, but the alignment of odd page number will be different from the even page. The code that I am presently trying is changing the alignment of both the odd and even pages,which is not desired

```
    ActiveDocument.Sections(i).PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
    Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = Not Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious
    ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(1).PageNumbers
        .NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleArabic
        .HeadingLevelForChapter = 0
        .IncludeChapterNumber = False
        .ChapterPageSeparator = wdSeparatorHyphen
        .RestartNumberingAtSection = False
        .StartingNumber = starts
        .Add (0)
    End With
End If
ActiveDocument.Sections(i).PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).LinkToPrevious = False
WordBasic.InsertAlignmentTab Alignment:=2, Relative:=0, Leader:=0
```

Comment: how do you define `no_format` variable here?? and other variables like `starts`, `continue`, `align`?? did you try to debug this code step-by-step?? Moreover, add bigger part of your code that would include opening for `end if` statement which is in 5th row before end...

Comment: no_format is a variable =1 signifying the page number style,continue is true and false for if it continues marking pages with the previous section, and align =0 for left alignment and align2 is alignment for right alignment, if-endif is used for positioning of page number in header or footer

Comment: thanks, these are important information. could you extend your code a bit too??

Comment: hope it's fixed. any feedback if it's working is welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that for odd and even pages you don't set `left` and `right` positions of page numbers but you need to set `outside` and `inside` positions of them.

So, try to change this tiny line:

```
.Add (0)
```

into one of possible 'odd-even' positions:

```
.Add wdAlignPageNumberOutside
.Add wdAlignPageNumberInside
```

Moreover, last line which is trying to insert 'tab' is not necessary then.