# How to Add Footers to Documents in Odd Pages and Even Pages

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

When I just want to use *C#* to insert footers to word programmatically, I cant make the odd pages and even pages display different content. The footers are always same in every page. I had refered some pages like

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178795.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178795(v=vs.90).aspx

However, I still dont know how to set different footers on odd pages and even pages.

If I changed `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` to `wdSeekEvenPagesFooter`, the footers lost.

```
section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
```

And Please **not use VB** to reply my questions, thank you!

Add:In Visual Studio 2012,`OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter` ask me to set a value of INT instead of a value of BOOL.Is that a Microsoft's bug???

Would someone help me?

Comment: do you have this property set to true? `.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True`

Comment: eh ,When I set .PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = 1,I get a error "Value is not within the expected range".    However When I set .PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = 0,there is no error and the question still exists.    To tell the truth,I cant set "True".I mean when i set .PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter =True,a red line will display under the "True".

Comment: I will not help you as you clearly stated to **not use VB** (which is wrong in my opinion as long as the logic of working with MS Office seems to be often similar whichever language you use), but you could try to analyse some possible logic as [presented here (VBA code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079070/assign-even-odd-page-numbers-in-word/16083333#16083333)

Comment: The reason I dont use VB ,is I found VB can solve my problem indeed.But when I change VB to C#,I got some errors.And I am not familiar with VB,So I want to know how to solve it with C#.,Thank you but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps to solve your problem

```
1> 0 implies false and -1 true so use .PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = -1

2> use WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages to access footer on even page

3> use WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage to access footer on odd page
```

Comment: ha... I never thought that-1 is equal to 'true' .'-1' works.Thank you ver